# changing data in a struct in python

Tags: python, string, data-structures, iterator

I am pretty new in python, and I have a problem I don't know how to solve.

For example, I have this struct with members such as administrator, berit, etc:

```
DEFAULT_DATA = {
'administrator': {
    'name': 'Admin',
    'pw': 'secret',
    'is_author': False,
    'is_admin': True
}
'berit': {
     'name': 'berit',
    'pw': 'apa',
    'is_author': False,
    'is_admin': False
 }
```

This data is then accessible via a method this method:

```
def DefaultData():
"""Provides default data for Gruyere."""
 return copy.deepcopy(DEFAULT_DATA)
```

I want to do a md5 hash on the passwords so they are not in plaintext, but I have no idea how to access the fields such as 'pw' and reassign a new value in python.

Here's a guess as to what it might be:

```
stored_data = data.DefaultData()
for member in stored_data:
   for field in member:
       if field=='pw':
           'pw' = md5.new(salt+pw).hexdigest()    // how do you access the value?
```

Comment: Perhaps read a Python tutorial. What you call structs are dictionaries, and they *exist* to allow simple and efficient access of values by a key (e.g. a string)...

Comment: If there was only a way to implement custom types with custom behavior, we wouldn't have to fiddle around with the default types ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in `stored_data` are themselves dictionaries.  Iterate over the values and apply your algorithm:

```
stored_data = data.DefaultData()
for data in stored_data.values():
    data['pw'] = md5(salt + data['pw']).hexdigest()

from pprint import pprint
pprint(stored_data)
```

#### Output

```
{'administrator': {'is_admin': True,
                   'is_author': False,
                   'name': 'Admin',
                   'pw': '33e7cb694fb6fb2f848af6774d9ff138'},
 'berit': {'is_admin': False,
           'is_author': False,
           'name': 'berit',
           'pw': '00c10978330d65eb0cb739a629b6ed15'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You access it through the dictionary interface.

```
stored_data = data.DefaultData()
for member in stored_data.itervalues():
    member['pw'] =  md5.new(salt + member['pw']).hexdigest()
```

Two comments:

- First, this doesn't change the value in `data`, because you're returning a copy of it in `DefaultData`.
- Second, as extra security, you might want to include the `name` field in the hash.  At least that way it won't be obvious if two users have the same password.

Comment: It is complaining about "String indices must be integer" at the assignment of member['pw']. Why isn't it treated as a dictionary?

Comment: `for member in stored_data` iterates over the keys, which are strings.  Iterate over the values.